# cocos2d 2.0 not loading ipad graphics

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

I have the suffixes for iPad and iPad retina screen devices defined as -ipad and -ipadhd for my ccFileUtils for my universal app, and I also have all my graphics included in the correct size for iPad and the retina iPad with the correct suffixes... However whenever I run the app in the simulator it shows the standard without suffix images :/ Like so...

[image: Like so]

Comment: Check what happens if you remove the image file without suffixes. Also try enabling the fallback suffixes: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/api-ref/latest_2.x/cocos2d-iphone/html/interface_c_c_file_utils.html#aa82ee0268a129a3db13bee674132f83f

Comment: Removing the file without suffixes does nothing on the retina iPad, but somehow still manages to use the without suffix file on the non-retina iPad! :/ which must mean that it is the -hd suffix that is being displayed on the iPad retina and the no suffix on the iPad... If I enable callback suffixes it uses the -hd suffix for both iPad and iPad retina...

Comment: so for some reason it's just not picking up my -ipad and -ipadhd suffixes at all :/

Comment: Try resetting your simulator settings (delete the app) and do a clean in xcode

Comment: @Sylvan Didn't work either... I've also tried saving all my files as -iPadhd (note capital p) and adding them all in and changing the suffix to -iPadhd... if I do that I get a `Couldn't add image :Background.png in CCTextureCache`

Comment: I decided to check whether all these fixes worked on non-retina iPad and it turns out they did, so the problem is now only with the -iPadhd suffix... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a silly error nothing to do with the coding in the end. I checked the file-type of the image in question (Background-iPadhd.png) and it turned out even though it has the extension .png it was in fact a .psd file. It's possible to accidentally save files with a .png extension but in the .psd format if you write the filename as xxx.png but leave the format as .psd when saving from photoshop.